# Many errors in console selenium - python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have code that contains a `while = True` and keeps repeating endlessly.

*(Note: I have already confirmed the stackoverflow of the code and it is behaving perfectly)*

Inside my While, I call several files one at a time, and these files create an instance of chrome and access a site and then close it. The problem is that this is generating me MANY errors in the console, so many that I even put in pastebin. Can someone help me ?

In pastebin, whenever you see `*x* already accessed` it is because it just did what you should on the site and already closed it.

---

I'm using chromedriver 79 (which is my chrome version), Python 3.8 and Windows 10

**Pastebin**: https://pastebin.com/JXRauZjm

---

### • Why are these errors bothering me?

Because to run the code 24 hours per day I'm using an Azure virtual machine, and when I leave my code running for about 5 hours, the Azure machine starts to get inaccessible (I believe the code is causing it to crash), I've tried to think in any other reason to crash,  but I can only find this one.)

---

### • For possible questions:

• To completely close the driver on each file, I am using:

`webdriver.quit ()
return "anything"`

• There are currently 12 files (12 webdrivers) that open and close every 3 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the logging level when you initialize your `WebDriver` instance:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3");
chrome_options.add_argument("--silent");
```

This [closed ChromeDriver issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=116) has a bit more information about the `--silent` flag.

Comment: Hmmm ... But isn't that a mistake? If I set `--silent`, it just won't show me any more errors, right? Is there any way to fix them?

Comment: I can't tell from your original question if you just don't want to see the console error messages, or if you actually want to troubleshoot what the console error messages mean. You said your code is behaving perfectly, so I assume the error messages in question are pieces of info. that you do not care about.